# Can I programmatically unstringify a symbol in C++/GCC/Ubuntu?

Tags: c++, gcc, cppunit

When I compile this (CppUnit) expression under GCC/Ubuntu

```
CPPUNIT_TEST_SUITE_NAMED_REGISTRATION(wcsdesign::tests::ConduitTestFixture, "wcsdesign_Conduit");
```

The value `wcsdesign::tests::ConduitTestFixture` winds up being stringified to `N9wcsdesign5tests18ConduitTestFixtureE`.

Is there any way I can programmatically retrieve the original string "wcsdesign::tests::ConduitTestFixture" given "N9wcsdesign5tests18ConduitTestFixtureE"?

Answer (score 1):

Prepend `_Z` to the symbol before passing it to [`abi::__cxa_demangle`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/ext_demangling.html). Then you get the original string back out.

Comment: note, the name mangling is not performed by the preprocessor (on first reading your question suggested it was about preprocessor macro behaviour)

Comment: @MattMcNabb is it not? It seems to get mangled in a macro when concatenating symbols with the `##` operator. Isn't the preprocessor responsible for that?

Comment: the preprocessor does `##` but it doesn't do name mangling. Can you post a testcase? (BTW you can use `gcc -E` to view the program after preprocessing)